# Set td value based on another td name from ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following table structre:

```
<tr>
  <td class="name">
    Stock1
  </td>
  <td class="price">

  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="name">
      Stock2
  </td>
  <td class="price">

  </td>
</tr>
```

Based on the names Stock1 and Stock2, I need to set the corresponding price in the next `td`. I am web scraping the price thru ajax and trying to set the value as follows:

For Stock1:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $.ajax({
          *everything else working fine*
          success: function(data) {
               if($('.name').html().indexOf("Stock1") != -1) {
                    $(this).closest('tr').find('.price').html(data);
               }
          }
     });
});
```

In this scenario, `this` is not working, which I'm expecting to be the `td` tag with class `name` where value is Stock1. If I replace `this` with `".name"`, the code works only if there's one `name` td. When I have two `td` tags with the class `name`, it doesn't work.

I need to get this done as soon as the document loads, and not on some event like mouse click or hover.

Comment: I did, but since I have two `td` tags with the same class, jquery doesn't know which one to select and it doesn't work. How do I select the `".name"` where the value is Stock1?

Comment: `this` have scope of ajax object, not your table

Comment: @Sojtin how to change the scope of `this` to my table, or make this work any other way around?

Comment: are you going to fire `ajax` for each and every name? Or there will be a single `ajax` getting back all the prices in single shot and then simply assign each individual price to respective node?

Comment: @vijayP firing ajax for each and every name

Comment: @BivoKasaju - then in that case i will suggest you to modify your server side code a bit to return back node name (like Stock1) as well as its price. So that your ajax success data will have 2 components; like `data.name` and `data.price`. first one will get used to target DOM `td` and later one will be used to set the price text.

Comment: @vijayP that is an excellent suggestion and I did that, could you please show me how to execute it in the jquery ajax success section? data.name and data.price isn't working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` doesn't refers to `td.name` element nor `table`.

The [`:contains()` Selector](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selects all elements that contain the specified text to target the `td` and then use can use DOM relationship to target immediate following sibling `td` using `.next()`.

```
$('td.name:contains("Stock1")').next('.price').html(data);
```

*or*

```
$('td.name:contains("Stock1")').closest('tr').find('.price').html(data);
```

You can also use `.filter()`

```
var var1 = 'Stock1';
$('td.name').filter(function(){
    return this.textContent.indexOf(var1) != -1;
}).closest('tr').find('.price').html(data);
```

---

As per comment, now you  are returning an array. So need to iterate the `data` object and target the desired element.

```
var data = [{
    name: "Stock1",
    price: "$12"
}, {
    name: "Stock2",
    price: "$15"
}]
$.each(data, function(_, d){
    $('td.name').filter(function() {
        return this.textContent.indexOf(d.name) != -1;
    }).closest('tr').find('.price').html(d.price);
})
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/zd8wx7jt/)

Comment: If I'm using a variable `var1` instead of the string "Stock1", do i simply replace "Stock1" with var1 without the qoutes?

Comment: @BivoKasaju, `$('td.name:contains("'+var1+'")')`

Comment: I think the for loop and ajax aren't working together, so I'm only getting the price for the last name in the list. Therefore, as @vijayP suggested, I returned both name and price in ajax from the server. How would you make the edit to integrate this in the code? `success: function (data)` and `data.name`, `data.price` isn't working.

Comment: for the above code, is the following server side code good enough: `string name="Stock1"; string price="15"; string[] returndata = {name, price}; return Json(returndata, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); `

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code in success method, assuming the data would be in the format mentioned below.

```
success:function(data)
      // Assigning dummy values for assumption
      var data = [{
        stockName: "Stock1",
        price: "$12"
      }, {
        stockName: "Stock2",
        price: "$15"
      }]
     // Iterating throw all td which has name [class] elements
      $(".name").each(function(i, obj) {
        // Dummy Validation as per the mock data to repalce the data as per the stockName
        if ($(this).closest('tr').find('.name').text().trim() === data[i].stockName){
          $(this).closest('tr').find('.price').html(data[i].price);
        }
      })
});
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/drq7ubnw/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function(data) {
  $('.name').each(function(index, element) {
    if ($(element).html().indexOf("Stock1") != -1) {
      $(element).closest('tr').find('.price').html(data);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Code dump is not useful. Please add few lines for explanation

Answer (score 0):

The current implementation may not work correctly if you have multiple Stocks are present on your page. So i will suggest you to modify your server side code a bit to return back node name (like Stock1) as well as its price. So that your ajax success `data` will have 2 components; like `data.name` and `data.price`. first one will get used to target DOM td and later one will be used to set the price text as follows:

For Stock1:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: "someBaseURL?name=Stock1"
        success: function(data) {
            var name = data.name; //grab the stock name
            var price = data.price; //grab the stock price
            //iterate over all the names and target the one associated
            $('.name').each(function(){
                if($.trim($(this).text()).indexOf(name) != -1)
                    $(this).closest('tr').find('.price').html(price);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: How should I return the data from server, in what format? I am using `string name="Stock1"; string price="15"; string[] returndata = {name, price}; return Json(returndata, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` Would this work with the code above?

Comment: you need to return it like: `string name="Stock1"; string price="15"; return Json(new {name = name, price = price}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: Ohh.. I just used data[0] and data[1] for my method of server side code and it worked lol

Comment: @BivoKasaju - thats great.